# Finding WebElement by Link Text that starts-with

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find a given link WebElement by partial link text but I want to leverage `starts-with` to make it more robust.  The WebElement I am trying to find is the second one in the following list ...

```
<a id="" class="" onmouseout="" href="some.random.href" target="" onmousedown="" onmouseup="" onmouseover="" title="" onclick=""> nsfoobar:80</a>
<a id="" class="" onmouseout="" href="some.other.random.href" target="" onmousedown="" onmouseup="" onmouseover="" title="" onclick=""> sfoobar:443</a>
```

I thought finding it by xpath and `starts-with` would be a good approach but it's throwing a NoSuchElementException ...

```
sfoobarXpath = "//a[starts-with(.,' sfoobar:')]";
driver.findElement(By.xpath(sfoobarXpath)).click();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT1:** Edited example to better illustrate problem

**EDIT2:** I need to be able to find this WebElement without knowledge of the text of the other WebElement; in my actual environment, there can be any number of these link elements and they're subject to change.

Comment: Have you tried "//a[starts-with(string(),' sfoobar:')]"

Comment: @Würgspaß Didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: did you try //a[starts-with(text(), ' sfoobar:')] ?

Comment: @aholt I did and that didn't work either, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this xpath expression:

```
**//a[normalize-space(substring-before(.,':'))='sfoobar']**
```

`substring-before(.,':')` retrieves the text content of the WebElement before the colon character.

`normalize-space()` removes the leading whitespace from the WebElement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the xpath `contains()` function

```
//a[contains(text(),'sfoobar')]
```

**Edit**

According to the OP's edit

```
//a[contains(text(),'sfoobar')and not(contains(text(),'nsfoobar'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I apologize my example WebElements didn't fully illustrate my problem.  See my edit above.

Comment: That looks ok to me. Have tried contains though? With contains you do not have to worry about the whitespace

Comment: How can I use contains though when both WebElements contain the string in question?

Comment: I am doing contains on text() and in your case the texts are different one is *nsfoobar* and the other is *sfoobar:*

Comment: Doesn't contains on text() still match on any element containing that text?  How does it differentiate between `nsfoobar` and `sfoobar` on the basis of containing `sfoobar` when they both do?

Comment: But is there any way to do it without knowing the text of the other WebElements?  Is it possible to use cssSelector on element text?  Like use a cssSelector like `"a[text()^='vCloud-GHS:']"` (that won't work because it throws an invalid selector exception but anything like it that would work?)

Comment: No, css does not give you the option for text based search. Give me the actual html and I would see if anything could be done

Answer (score 0):

As per the html you have given in your question, and your requirement of using `starts-with`, you can try the below xpath:

```
//a[not(starts-with(text(),' n'))]
```

Note:- The above will select the link that doesn't have innerHTML or text starting with " n" **(there is a space before 'n' as is given in the html so provided)**.

Comment: I need to be able to accomplish this without having to rely on knowing the text of other WebElements.

Comment: In that case, please provide html code that can be worked with.. What you have provided  as of now,  sadly isn't helping. :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just finding all the link elements by partial link text and iterating through that list to find the one with substring before the `:` that exactly equals `sfoobar`.  It's not the most elegant solution but it seems to work ...

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("sfoobar"));
if(links.isEmpty()) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find any links.");           
}
else {
    for(WebElement link:links) {
        if(StringUtils.substringBefore(link.getText(),":").equals("sfoobar")) {
            link.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```